# Vim statusline does not expand color/highlight group from expression

Tags: vim, colors, highlight, expansion, statusline

I wrote a function which returns a string:

```
function! StatusBricks()
    let l:stat = Brick(statusbricks#ReportLinecount('raw'), {
        \ 'brick_color': 'LineNr',
        \ 'delimiter_position': 'right',
        \ 'delimiter_right': '❯'
        \ })
    return l:stat
endfunction
```

The result has the following format, generated by `Brick()`:

```
%#HighlightGroup#SomeData
```

When I use the function as an expression inside the statusline I expect the `highlight group` to get expanded in order to colorize the appropriate statusline section:

```
set statusline =%{StatusBricks()}
```

But what I get is a statusline literally showing `%#HighlightGroup#ExpandedData` rather than `ExpandedData`:

[image: vim statusline highlight group expansion]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The result of `%{` isn't interpreted further, however the result of `%!` is. Use

```
set statusline=%!StatusBricks()
```

`%!` doesn't appear to have a tag in the helpfile, but it's mentioned near the beginning of `:help 'statusline'`.

**Following your comment:** if you want different colours in the statusline depending on the state of each particular window, then you can highlight an empty string if you don't want a particular highlight to appear. E.g.

```
set stl=%#error#%r%#search#
```

Only read-only windows (e.g. open a help buffer) will have the read-only flag displayed in red. Admittedly this can get complicated depending on your highlighting requirements.

Comment: Help isn't quite clear about further interpretion of `%{}`. Maybe I missed something. However `%!` has a sideeffect: From `help`: "Note that the "%!" expression is evaluated in the context of the current window and buffer, while %{} items are evaluated in the context of the window that the statusline belongs to." As a consequence `%!` is not really useful unfortunately.

Comment: See the edit, if that's what you mean. Maybe you could include more detail and code in your question so we know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When using `%!`, you can use `winbufnr(g:statusline_winid)` in your function to identify the buffer whose statusline you are drawing.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr - use `{%` `%}`

I realise this is an old question, but I found an answer that future readers might use.

Rather than

`set statusline =%{StatusBricks()}`

you need

`set statusline =%{%StatusBricks()%}`

From `:help 'statusline'`:

```
    {% -  This is almost same as { except the result of the expression is
          re-evaluated as a statusline format string.  Thus if the
          return value of expr contains % items they will get expanded.
          The expression can contain the } character, the end of
          expression is denoted by %}.
          The For example:
            func! Stl_filename() abort
                return "%t"
            endfunc

            `stl=%{Stl_filename()}`   results in `"%t"`
            `stl=%{%Stl_filename()%}` results in `"Name of current file"`
```